# How to add in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, addition

```
while (studentRecords.readNextRecord()) {
    currentZipCode       =  studentRecords.getStudentZipCode();
    currentGender        =  studentRecords.getStudentGender();

    if (currentZipCode === FIRST_ZIPCODE) {
        if (currentGender === "M")
        document.write("53711: Males: " + currentGender + "<br />");
    }
}
```

How can I add all the M's together to produce 
53711: Males: 5??

Comment: are you asking for how to count all record having `currentGender == M` then display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a running count, and don't output the total until you're done with the loop.

```
var males = 0;

while (studentRecords.readNextRecord()) {
  currentZipCode       =  studentRecords.getStudentZipCode();
  currentGender        =  studentRecords.getStudentGender();

  if (currentZipCode === FIRST_ZIPCODE) {
    if (currentGender === "M") {
      ++males;
    }
  }
}

document.write("53711: Males: " + males + "<br />");
```